# Defining DataContract and DataMember dynamically in Generic Classes

Tags: c#, class, generics, serialization, attr

I want to create a generic class in C# and control the way it is serialized by defining its `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes dynamically, according to the generic type parameter used in the constructor.

Is there a way to do so? Can we define those atributes in runtime using reflection in the generic class constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Attributes are declared statically on compile-time and cannot be introduced on run-time. They are part of an assembly's metadata.

Side note: In purely custom scenarios, where you'd control the *consumer* of attributes, it would be possible to make a custom attribute repository instead of using reflection directly. However, this is not the case of `DataContractSerializer`.